# Spring Integration custom processing order not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, integration

I have configured spring integration to poll a directory. I have configured InBoundChannelAdaptor with poller configuration of

**maxMessagesPerPoll = -1
trigger = PeriodicTrigger(1000)**

Also I have provided custom comparator while creating the FileReadingMessageSource, to process the files based on modification datetime.

```
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource(new Comparator<File>(){
    
    @Override
    public int compare(File a , File b)
    {
            if(a.lastModified() > b.lastModified())
            {
                   return 1;
            }else{
                    return -1;
            }
    }


})
```

My folder is having 2000 files, but files are not processing in the lastModified manner, means the oldest file should process first, but it is not happening.

Comment: We probably need to know more about your downstream processing. Perhaps you do some thread shifting over there breaking the mentioned order.

Comment: As of now, doing nothing, just printing the filename to check. Also, if I remove the custom ordering, by default as per the Spring Docs, it processes in Natural Ordering of path, which is working perfectly fine. But what I want is file should get process in FIFO order instead of natural ordering of path.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me as expected:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow lastModifiedOrderFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
                    Files.inboundAdapter(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads"),
                            Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified)),
                    e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)))
            .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
            .get();
}
```

We probably need to know more about your setup.